# Python - Tree without classes

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

How can I implement a tree without using classes in python? I can only use lists, dictionaries and queue. Obviously without the library *bintree*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def Tree():
    return defaultdict(Tree)
```

Usage:

```
>>> records = Tree()
>>> records['Artist']['Maria Callas']['Song']['O Mio Babbino Caro']['Year'] = 1965
```

bonus: Maria Callas singing [O Mio Babbino Caro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1C8NFDdFYg)

Comment: I was looking for something that doesn't use any libraries. But thank you Peter!

Comment: You said you could use queues, but [Python's tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-queues) says to implement them using [**`deque`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which also lives in the builtin [**`collections`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module along with `defautldict`. I'm not sure I understand your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
{'value': None, 'nodes': []}
```

to represent each node.

For example:

[image]

Can be represented as:

```
{'value': '+', 'nodes': 
     [
       {'value': '2', 'nodes': []}, 
       {'value': '*', 'nodes': 
           [
              {'value': '3', 'nodes': []}, 
              {'value': '5', 'nodes': []}
           ]
       }
     ]
}
```

NOTE: Just for educational purpose. There are more efficient data structures already implemented.

Comment: Thank you Hamlet,  that was exactly what I was looking for!